# Is there a quick option to save the JWT token secure?

Tags: reactjs, api, security

While following a MERN stack tutorial i am asking myself if it is safe to store the JWT token inside localstorage. After 1 sec of googling i got an answer like "definetly not".

The current api call is as follows:

```
const {data} = await Axios.post("/api/users/signin", {email, password});
localStorage.setItem('localUserInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
```

I am wondering, because the lecturer uses other safe techniques like using roles and bcrypt (and react should be protected against xss).

So if it is not: Is there another quick option to save it secure?

Comment: Please just use cookie-based sessions with the appropriate settings (sameSite, httpOnly, secure). Don't use JWTs on the client-side unless you know what you are doing: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [http-only cookie](https://www.cookiepro.com/knowledge/httponly-cookie/) to prevent malicious scripts from reading sensible cookie data, e.g. in to use them in [Cross Site Scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) attacks.

Since you mentioned you are learning the MERN stack -- You can use the [cookie-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session) [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), learn more about security in express [here](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-cookies-securely).

It offers multiple configurations to make session cookies secure:

```
app.use(session({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
  cookie: {
    secure: true, // enforce https
    httpOnly: true, // ensure cookies are only sent via http(s)
    domain: 'example.com', // specify hosts that are allowed to receive the cookie
    expires: expiryDate // define lifespan
  }
}))
```